# Tempopunkteco/daŭreco de iuj verboj

Tags: verbs

Estas al mi iuj verboj, kiuj estas kvazaŭ aŭ esence aŭ subkomprenite tempopunkta. Ekzemple, morto, fino, komenco, ktp. Se oni dirus, ke iu mortis, aŭ ke io finiĝis aŭ komenciĝis, estas al mi pli ofte subkomprenite ke tiuj okazis je tempopunktoj, kaj verŝajne ne je ia daŭro. Konsidere ke verbo Esperanta ne montras (aŭ laŭ desegno devus ne montri) aspekton je verboj, estas al mi iomete strange ke tia subkompreno estas.

Kiel ekzemplo, kiom kurioza laŭ vi ŝajnas tiu frazo? Kiel malkuriozigus/klarigus vi ĝin?

> Li mortis, sed li ne mortis.

Denove (se vi jam vidis iujn miajn demandojn antaŭajn), mi ja scias ke ja eblus uzi participon (ekz "li estis mortanta") se estus sufiĉe konvene/klare tiel esprimi la nuancon, sed mi scivolas la kutimon por tiu okazo kurioza.

Comment: Kiu estas la fakta demando? Mi supozas ke ne temas pri klarigo de `Li mortis sed li ne mortis`, kiu povas havi tiom da klarigoj kiom da kuntekstoj.

Comment: "Li mortis tamen ne daŭris", subita ekmorto. (Se mi prave komprenis.) Mi eble formulus: **lia morto estis sen transiro / subita**.